# How can I get Management Studio 2005 to copy the headers from result sets?

Tags: ssms

By default when you copy/paste data from a query window in SSMS it does not copy the column headings. How can I get these headers to be copied along with the data?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Open **Tools** menu
2. Open **Options...**
3. Expand **Query Results**
4. Expand **SQL Server**
5. Expand **Results to Grid**
6. Check **Include column headers when copying or saving the results**

Note that this will only work on the "New Query" types of windows -- not the "Open table" (editable) windows.

Answer (score 1):

Results with headers was added in SSMS 2008. Ctrl-Shift-C works as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can just right click the results, and select "Copy with headers"

Comment: Which version? I don't see the option in 2005 (yes, I just added 2005 to the question)

Comment: @Joe Phillips - SQL 2008. I couldn't remember if it was in 2005 or not as I don't have 2005 on this machine!

Comment: Thanks. That's good to know that they put some thought into this scenario in the next version :)